# Problem with spyder IDE console with linux

Tags: python, console, spyder

I've made a pip installation of Spyder in a python virtual environment on my Ubuntu desktop.

I had an another environment for an OpenGL project. I wanted spyder to execute my code with this environment not the one it is installed on.
So I've been to spyder parameter set the location of my environment in Spyder and it seems accepted it.

But now once I've try it using F5 nothing happened. I've tryed to launch a new spyder console, relaunch spyder's kernel but it doesn't worked.

I've noticed that I can't write anything directly on my spyder console and I got a strange message while trying to re-launch spyder's kernel:
*"Python 3.10.4 (main, Apr  2 2022, 09:04:19) [GCC 11.2.0]
Type "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
IPython  -- An enhanced Interactive Python.
Cannot restart a kernel not started by Spyder"*

I dont know what's wrong my installation on a Venv or the fact that I want to use an another venv

Thanks for reading

Comment: Did you install spyder-kernels on the env you want Spyder to use? Maybe this could be useful: https://docs.spyder-ide.org/current/troubleshooting/common-illnesses.html

Answer (score 2):

I solved the Problem.

I reinstalled Spyder in the virtual environment and it worked.

There are issues with pip packages when Spyder has to call scripts in another virtual environment. I suggest to install spyder in the virtual environment you intend to use it.